# What happens when you drop "étale" from the construction of étale fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Haven't thought about this deeply; it just came up at lunch and I wondered if anyone knew the answer.

To define the étale fundamental group of a scheme $X$, we fix a point $x_0 \in X$, look at the category $\mathcal{C}$ of finite étale morphisms to $X$, take the functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which takes a element $Y \xrightarrow{f} X \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ to the fiber $f^{-1}(x_0)$.  $F$ is pro-representable, and taking automorphisms gives us $\pi^{ét}_1(X, x_0)$.

Suppose we drop the étale condition in the definition of $\mathcal{C}$, so that we're looking at branched covers instead of unramified ones.  Presumably we'll need to define $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathsf{Sch}$ as taking scheme-theoretic fibers.

Does this construction go through and give us some kind of object encoding information about arbitrary branched coverings?

Comment: Suppose $X = \text{Spec } k$. Then the category of finite morphisms to $X$ is the category of finite-dimensional commutative $k$-algebras. This seems to me like a pretty complicated category even when $k$ is algebraically closed, and in particular should be very far from being the kind of category one can run Grothendieck's Galois theory on.

Comment: The group would be very large: consider $\mathbb{P}^1$(over $\mathbb{C}$) as an example. It's ramified double cover can be of arbitrary genus.

Comment: Well, finite-dimensional $k$-algebras are in particular artinian, so the structure theorem tells us they are finite products of artinian local $k$-algebras; and when $k$ is algebraically closed, then these are all just infinitesimal extensions of $k$. So on the Galois side instead of having the category of finite sets one has a category of some kind of finite sets with infinitesimal extensions...

Comment: To my knowledge, there's no reasonable classification of **all** even connected zero-(Krull-)dimensional schemes over $k$ (algebraically closed or not). In particular the set of such is too big to be classified by a finite-dimensional moduli space, since there are "fat points" in ambient spaces of arbitrary dimension. (That said, if we fix an ambient space and length, then we get the Hilbert scheme of points. So that's a start.)

Comment: This seems like a strange question. It seems like the answer you get, if there is one, won't be morally the same as in the etale case. For example, the rigidity of covers no longer holds--morphisms aren't determined by their actions on geometric points. This makes the action of this new "pi_1" a little hard to think about, imo.  I haven't thought about it, but your first thing you'd want to check is that this category is Galois.

Comment: "It seems like the answer you get, if there is one, won't be morally the same as in the etale case."

Well, yes. For instance, I strongly doubt the thing you'd get would be a group -- I imagine the things corresponding to ramified covers aren't invertible.

Comment: Similar question with "finite" dropped: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316171